# Why is my unix socket created with a different ACL mask to other files?

Tags: linux, centos7, access-control-list, socket, setfacl

I am deploying an Nodejs Express app. It is going to run as on the same box as an Nginx server, which will proxy requests to it via a unix socket. The question is not specific to Nodejs, however.

The express app runs as user `nodejs`, and nginx runs as `nginx`.

My plan is to create a `/sockets` directory owned by `nodejs` for Express to put sockets in, and to grant `nginx` access to those sockets via a default ACL on the directory. Feel free to tell me if this is a silly idea, but keep in mind that's not my core question.

I create ACLs on the directory by running, as root,

```
setfacl -Rd --mask -m nginx:rw  /sockets
setfacl -R  --mask -m nginx:rwX /sockets
```

The directory then has the following ACLs: (tabulation by me for legibility in the question)

```
# file: /sockets
# owner: nodejs
# group: root
user:      : rwx
user: nginx: rwx
group:     : r-x
mask:      : rwx
other:     : r-x
default: user:     :rwx
default: user:nginx:rw-
default:group:     :r-x
default: mask:     :rwx
default:other:     :r-x
```

If, running as `nodejs`, I write to a file, it is created appropriately:

```
sudo -su nodejs
touch /sockets/testFile
getfacl /sockets/testFile

# file: /sockets/testFile
# owner: nodejs
# group: nodejs
user:     :rw-
user:nginx:rw-
group:    :r-x                      #effective:r--
mask:     :rw-
other:    :r--
```

Great!

However, if Node creates a socket by calling `listen()` on a path in this directory , it is created with an ACL `mask` that prevents `nginx` from accessing it.

```
const e = require('express')()
e.listen('/sockets/testSocket', (e) => console.error(e))

getfacl /sockets/testSocket 
# file: /sockets/testSocket
# owner: nodejs
# group: nodejs
user:     :rwx
user:nginx:rw-                  #effective:r--
group:    :r-x
mask:     :r-x
other:    :r-x
```

If I create an ordinary file with Nodejs in `/sockets` (e.g. by `fs.writeFile`) it is created with the same permissions as when I ran `touch /sockets/testFile` above, so I don't think it's a problem of Node's `umask`.

Likewise, if I run equivalent code to bind to a socket in `python`, the results are the same, so I don't think it's a problem with Node itself.

Obviously, this is stopping Nginx from talking to my Express app. Can anyone work out why? :/ The server is running CentOS 7.

Comment: I'm currently experiencing the same issue. Were you ever able to resolve it?

Comment: @DominicP I ended up running `umask 022` before `node`, from memory.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for reply. I'm hacking it by manually running `fs.chmod` on the socket from my app when it starts [like this](https://gist.github.com/visnup/9801864).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that socket() is a libc function that doesn't implement the ACL policies that are documented at 100%.

Through experimentation I found that you have to set the umask for the calling process, which according to ACL rules should *not* matter when creating files, and to successfully create sockets the way you want to, you have to:

```
umask 0002
setfacl -d -m user:nginx:rwx /sockets
setfacl -d -m group::rwx /sockets
setfacl -d -m mask::rwx /sockets
```